# Laravel: is it possible to set a controller dynamically for a route?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

So, lets say I do have a simple Controller that handles Books.

```
App\Http\Controllers\SimpleBooksController
```

Inside `routes.php` I register a route for it:

```
Route::get('books/{id}','SimpleBooksController@doSimpleStuff');
```

But the world of books is not so simple. So I would like to have another Controller that handles the really complex book stuff.

In my head I imagine that something like this would be really useful:

```
class ComplexBooksController extends SimpleBooksController
```

So that routes that are not explicitly handled by the child class fall back to the parent class.

Now let's say each book knows if it is complex or not: `$book->isComplex`

And what I would like to do would be something like this

```
if (!$book->isComplex) {
    // route 'books/{id}' to SimpleBooksController@doSimpleStuff
} else {
    // route 'books/{id}' to ComplexBooksController@doComplexStuff
}
```

So, how could one accomplish this?

*** edit ***

The way I am currently handling this, is by setting the Controllers in routes.php statically, but let them listen to parameterized routes:

```
Route::get('books/simple/{id}', 'SimpleBooksController@doSimpleStuff');
Route::get('books/complex/{id}', 'ComplexBooksController@doComplexStuff');
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [responses documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses), you should be able to use an anonymous function and return a redirect to the correct controller.

This assumes you have the data in a books table with `isComplex`:

```php
Route::get('books/{id}', function($id) {

    $result = DB::select('SELECT is_complex FROM books WHERE id = ?', [$id]);

    if (empty($result)) abort(404);

    $book = $result[0];

    if ($book->is_complex)
        return redirect()->action('SimpleBooksController@doSimpleStuff');
    else
        return redirect()->action('ComplexBooksController@doComplexStuff');

});
```

Comment: Note that this will be two separate requests.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I thought should be possible with laravel. But one problem exists, if I have multiple routes that follow this pattern I have to write this anonymous function multiple times with basically the same code. Only the actions inside the Controllers would change. So maybe there is another way to approach this? Maybe use middleware to that? (I have only been working with laravel for 1 week now, please excuse my naivety).

Answer (score 2):

Your approaching this in the wrong way. You should not be trying to handle it with different controllers and routes.

A route for books should be the same - regardless of the book.

Your controller then makes a determination if the book is simple or complex - and calls the appropriate Command to handle this.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('books/{id}','BooksController@doSimpleStuff');
```

**Controller:**

```
class BooksController extends Controller
{
      public function showBook($book)
      {
           if ($book->isComplex()) {
                $this->dispatch(new HandleComplexBook($book));
           } else {
                $this->dispatch(new HandleSimpleBook($book));
           }
      }

}
```

Then you just have two commands - one for simple books, and one for complex books

```
class HandleComplexBook extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $book;

    public function __construct(Book $book)
    {
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Handle the logic for a complex book here
    }

}

class HandleSimpleBook extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    protected $book;

    public function __construct(Book $book)
    {
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Handle the logic for a simple book here
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not really convinced that this is the way to go for my application. Mainly because I am not worried about the handling 'behind the scenes' - you can create a book, you can view a book, maybe you can buy a book. That is the same code whether I am dealing with a complex book or with a simple one.

Comment: *** It is the User Interface that I want to upgrade for complex books. Maybe pull in some additional book data via ajax or whatever. The Complex Book has an 'enriched' UI. So maybe its better to describe the SimpleController as the DefaultController and the ComplexController as CustomController. Where the DefaultController will be sufficient for 95% and the CustomController handles those special cases.